# What supermarket fish is good for frying, besides tilapia?

Tags: frying, fish, tilapia

I've been frying tilapia fillets in flour for a while and I like it, easy and tasty, just getting a bit tired of the same fish. Is there any other fish available in most supermarkets that is just as good for frying (I know some fish can't be fried easily)? I'm not looking for any exotic dishes, just some basic fried fish fillets to mix things up a bit.

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 3):

Farm-raised fried catfish is very popular in the US South, and not much more expensive than Tillapia.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to catfish, basa (a Vietnamese catfish) fries very nicely, as does haddock or cod.  Basa has the advantage of being inexpensive as well.  Any firm white fish is a good candidate for frying, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

Tilapia is actually a bit on the delicate side, so if you're able to pan-fry it to your liking, then any fish as firm or firmer would be good.

Trout or milkfish (bangus) are both quite delightful pan-fried. A very popular breakfast or brunch in The Philippines is [daing na bangus](http://panlasangpinoy.com/2016/02/21/daing-na-bangus-fried-milkfish-marinated-in-vinegar/), the same recipe pairs brilliantly with trout as well. Consider leaving the skin on :)

Another thing to try is asking your supermarket fishmonger for belly cuts; halibut belly is positively amazing pan-fried. I use cold-pressed grapeseed oil for frying fish because it's so flavor neutral and has a very high smoke point, but vegetable or palm oil would work just as well for the recipe I linked above.

Anyway, in short - go for the denser, meatier fish. Use a good quality and healthy oil. And don't be afraid to try searing it in a pan and finishing it in a hot oven. If it feels like it's going to flake more easily than tilapia, you're probably going to need some practice before you can start and finish it in a pan.

Answer (score 2):

These are high quality fishes you can fry at home:  silver pomfret, grouper, mullets, black sea bream, red snapper, carp, and tilapia.